# Python file handling error whenever email is entered wrong

Tags: python

Whenever the password is entered and it is wrong it says "incorrect attempt number" whatever. However when my email is wrong it will give me an error message and not the same thing as a wrong password does. I tried constructing another if loop for the email but that did not work.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Theater.py", line 126, in <module>
TheaterFileLogin()
File "E:\Theater.py", line 56, in TheaterFileLogin
Emaildex = Emails1.index(Email)
ValueError: 's,dm' is not in list
```

The code is:

```
import csv
x=0
while x<3:
    with open('Theater.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        Theater = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        Emails1 = []
        Passwords1 = []
        Passwords2 = []
        Passwords3 = []
        Passwords4 = []
        Firstnames = []
        Surnames = []
        for row in Theater:
            Firstname = row [1]
            Surname = row [0]
            Email1 = row[2]
            Password1 = row[7]
            Password2 = row[8]
            Password3 = row[9]
            Password4 = row[10]
            Firstnames.append(Firstname)
            Surnames.append(Surname)
            Emails1.append(Email1)
            Passwords1.append(Password1)
            Passwords2.append(Password2)
            Passwords3.append(Password3)
            Passwords4.append(Password4)
        Email = input("Email Adress: ")
        Password = input("Password: ")
        Emaildex = Emails1.index(Email)
        thepassword = Passwords1[Emaildex]
        adminlevel1password = Passwords2[Emaildex]
        adminlevel2password = Passwords3[Emaildex]
        adminlevel3password = Passwords4[Emaildex]
        FN = Firstnames[Emaildex]
        SN = Surnames[Emaildex]
        if thepassword == Password:
            print("Welcome")
            x=5
        else:
            print("Incorect email or password try again")
            x+=1
            print("Attempt",x)
```

Comment: Your code is rather inefficient. Why do you throw away all the data from the csv file and re-read it all again if the password is wrong? I _guess_ you want to give the user 3 chances to supply a correct email address and corresponding password. If so, you should say that in your question.

Comment: The short answer is that you are trying to get the index of an item from the list that doesn't exist. There are no checks in place to ensure that the email that's entered is valid, so when it tries to set Emaildex, it will fail since it doesn't find that value in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You get a `ValueError` when you attempt to find the index of a non-existent item in a list. There are two ways to deal with that.You could put `Emails1.index(Email)` inside a
[`try:` `except ValueError:`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), block but it's simpler to just test if `Email` is in `Emails1`.

Here's an improved version of your code that *should* do what you want. Note that I open the CSV file with `'rb'` mode, as recommended in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), although this isn't strictly necessary in Python 3.

```
import csv

with open('Theater.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    Theater = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    Emails1 = []
    Passwords1 = []
    Passwords2 = []
    Passwords3 = []
    Passwords4 = []
    Firstnames = []
    Surnames = []
    for row in Theater:
        Firstname = row [1]
        Surname = row [0]
        Email1 = row[2]
        Password1 = row[7]
        Password2 = row[8]
        Password3 = row[9]
        Password4 = row[10]
        Firstnames.append(Firstname)
        Surnames.append(Surname)
        Emails1.append(Email1)
        Passwords1.append(Password1)
        Passwords2.append(Password2)
        Passwords3.append(Password3)
        Passwords4.append(Password4)

for attempt in range(1, 4):
    Email = input("Email Address: ")
    Password = input("Password: ")
    if Email in Emails1:
        Emaildex = Emails1.index(Email)
        thepassword = Passwords1[Emaildex]
        if thepassword == Password:
            break
    print("Incorrect email or password.")
    if attempt < 3:
        print("Please try again.")
    print("Attempt", attempt)
else:
    print("Aborting.")
    exit()

print("Welcome")

adminlevel1password = Passwords2[Emaildex]
adminlevel2password = Passwords3[Emaildex]
adminlevel3password = Passwords4[Emaildex]
FN = Firstnames[Emaildex]
SN = Surnames[Emaildex]
```